# Debug a Bash Shell Script that calls a PHP method

Tags: php, bash, shell, debugging

I need to debug a method from my PHP project to make some changes. This method only runs when I launch the Bash Script so I can't see the content of a variable from that method with a var_dump().

This is how the Script Bash works and as I say, I need to know the content of certain variables of the method it calls to make some changes.

```
php /var/www/project/httpdocs/bin/console project:checkFiles 1 &>> $LOG_FILE
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$LOG_FILE` should contain all the output of the php command, your `var_dump`s will be there

Answer (score 1):

You can print it

```
 public function your_func()
 {
     $some_var = '1234';    
    
     echo $some_var . '#INFO: '.__FUNCTION__.' # '. PHP_EOL;    
    ....
 }
```

OR wirte to logs file

[fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)